# Why does the Gemara say Chizkiyahu didn't sing?

Tags: song-poetry, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, contradiction, king-hezekiah

The Gemara in [Sanhedrin 94a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.94a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that the reason Chizkiyahu was not the Mashiach is that he didn't sing after Hashem did miracles for him (Rashi adds that this refers to saving Yerushalayim from Sancheriv and healing Chizkiyahu):

> אמרה מדת הדין לפני הקב"ה רבש"ע ומה דוד מלך ישראל שאמר כמה שירות ותשבחות לפניך לא עשיתו משיח חזקיה שעשית לו כל הנסים הללו ולא אמר שירה לפניך תעשהו משיח לכך נסתתם
>
> The attribute of justice said before the Holy One, Blessed be He: Master of the Universe, and if with regard to David, king of Israel, who recited several songs and praises before You, You did not designate him as the Messiah, then with regard to Hezekiah, for whom You performed all these miracles, delivering him from Sennacherib and healing his illness, and he did not recite praise before You, will You designate him as the Messiah? It is for that reason that the mem was closed, because there was an opportunity for redemption that was thwarted.

Yet we find in Yishayahu that Chizkiyahu seemingly does sing! (Isaiah 38:9-20). He even promises to sing to Hashem his whole life:

> יְהוָ֖ה לְהוֹשִׁיעֵ֑נִי וּנְגִנוֹתַ֧י נְנַגֵּ֛ן כָּל־יְמֵ֥י חַיֵּ֖ינוּ עַל־בֵּ֥ית יְהוָֽה׃
>
> “[It has pleased] the LORD to deliver us, That is why we offer up music All the days of our lives At the House of the LORD.”

Does anyone have a good resolution of these sources?

Comment: Does he follow through on that promise?

Comment: No matter how much singing he did, the fact remained that after the confrontation w/Assyria, he was a tribute-paying vassal with a greatly reduced kingdom and subject population. Not exactly a worldwide-recognized candidate for Moshiach.  Unlike the residents of Lachish and all the other lost cities, they were still alive and in Jerusalem, or its suburbs, in contrast to so many other kingdoms that revolted and were totally destroyed, so they had good reason to sing.

Comment: @DoubleAA The "michtav" found in Yishayahu itself seems to be such a song.

Comment: @Gary I'm not asking about why he wasn't Mashiach. I'm asking about the Gemara's reason.

Comment: True.  Your first sentence mentioned a possible reason our ancestors thought he wasn't Moshiach.  I was just trying to add some more background context to the historical situation.

Comment: @Gary, who says that Chizkiyahu remained a tribute-paying vassal after Sancheriv's army was wiped out? In fact, pesukim such as והיה ביום ההוא יסור סבלו מעל שכמך ועלו מעל צוארך (Isaiah 10:27) seem to say quite otherwise.

Comment: @Meir - the Assyrian annals - either in Pritchard's ANET or one of the other inscription compendiums.  They kept pretty good records of what their vassals paid yearly, as well as one-time gifts, like when Jehu gave his tribute as recorded on Shalmanezzer's Black Obelisk, or when Menachem paid to confirm himself as King, and labor/material "contributions" for royal building projects, like Manassah is recorded as paying.

Comment: @Gary, I'll plead ignorance of those, since I'm no Assyriologist and am not familiar with those compendia. But we do have to ask - when we consider how often nowadays we see people stating "facts" that bear little to no relationship with the truth - how reliable these annals are. Who's to say they're not just "fake news" to glorify the king? (Not unlike the way the kings of England continued to claim to be "kings of France" for centuries after they lost their last territories there.) By contrast, לא תהא תורה שלמה שלנו כשיחה בטלה שלהם.

Comment: Also, come to think of it, are the annals recording Chizkiyahu as paying tribute only before the attempted conquest, or after it too? If only the former, then sure, at that point he was a vassal, but that doesn't tell us anything about his status vis-a-vis Assyria after that.

Comment: @Meir - Here's a translation of one of the main records, a six column prism - http://www.kchanson.com/ANCDOCS/meso/sennprism1.html    The relevant parts start at the bottom of column 2 and continue through column 3.  Note that he spent a lot of time and effort campaigning in Babylon - Merodoch-Baladan gave him quite a bit of trouble, which why he was friends with Hezekiah, revolting against Assyria.

Comment: @Gary, so indeed that's talking about the events during Sennacherib's invasion; it doesn't tell us anything about what happened after the destruction of the army (which, to be sure, isn't mentioned there at all), hence no reason to think that Chizkiyahu remained a tribute-paying vassal afterwards.

Comment: @Meir - Line 35 in the 3rd column says that he added to "the former tribute" which was a yearly payment, indicating it resumed after the revolt failed, as well as line 49 saying he accepted servitude, which was not a temporary condition for kings Sennacherib allowed to remain ruling.  And btw, there was plenty of army left, since he campaigned often afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

The shirah he sang was about his recovery, not about the defeat of Sancheriv. Yalkut Shimoni ([Nach 243](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Nach.243.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), end) actually says that Hashem had to force the issue by making Chizkiyahu fall sick, so that at least he would say shirah for that:

> כשעלה סנחריב עליו הפילו האלקים לפניו הוה ליה למימר שירה על מפלתו ולא אמר, ומה היה לו הפילו האלקים במטה וחלה כדי שיאמר שירה שנאמר מכתב לחזקיהו:

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm wondering how to fit this in with the fact that Chizkiyahu fell sick before Sancheriv was actually defeated (Isaiah 38:6).

Comment: Also, Rashi's comment on Sanhedrin is still difficult to understand, because he did at least sing about his recovery